# Displaying script tags with React Helmet

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I posted earlier about needing to add some script tags into a react.js component. Not ideal but its not my choice. So I need to display a list of jobs from an external site:

```
<script src='https://www.workable.com/assets/embed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
whr(document).ready(function(){
whr_embed(266675, {detail: 'titles', base: 'jobs', zoom: 'country', grouping: 'none'});
});
</script>
<div id="whr_embed_hook"></div>
```

I have tried to use the react-Helmet and injecting the above script tags into the page's HEAD tag that needs to display the list.

So far I have tried:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
...
return(
      <Helmet>
        <script src="https://www.workable.com/assets/embed.js" />
        <script type="javascript">
          {`
              whr(document).ready(function(){
                  whr_embed(266675, { detail: 'titles', base: 'jobs', zoom: 'country', grouping: 'none' });
              });
            `}
        </script>
      </Helmet>
...

      <div className="container-thin">
        <div id="whr_embed_hook" />
      </div>

)
```

The site compiles fine and I can see the two script tags injected into the Head for this page when I run it on my localhost, but the list of jobs do not show inside the target div tag.

I dont know if Im missing something above or is the a better way in anyone's opinion?

Thanks
Jools

Comment: dont put the script tags in the head of the page.